# Issues with rotated divs not expanding across the whole page and alignment of containers within rotated div

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make my rotated divs cover across the whole page without making a scroll bar pop up. I am also trying to figure out how to get my container-subs in the pricing section to align horizontally, as they currently follow the rotation.

My repo is here - https://github.com/Jacwilalasey/Smart-Contrax

Demo is here - https://jacwilalasey.github.io/Smart-Contrax/

Thank you!

HTML

```
        <h2>About Us</h2>
        <img src="./images/about.png" alt="">
        <p>We believe blockchain cybersecurity is not only about asset protection but a whole new way of doing Web3: without scams and hacks, rug pulls, wash trading, and circulation supply manipulations. New Web3 is about respecting your community, being honest with your investors and partners, acting responsibly, and valuing reputation.</p>
    </article>

    <section id="services">
        <h2>Our Services</h2>
        <p>Protect your project from vulnerabilities and show users your focus on security. Due to vulnerabilities in smart contracts, your project may lose money, reputation, and time. Users look at security when making an investment decision. Smart contract auditing services remove these vulnerabilities.</p>
        <img src="./images/serv.png" alt="">
    </section>

    <section id="pricing">
        <h2>Pricing</h2>

        <div class="container-sub">
            <h3>£15 <span>p/m</span></h3>
            <p><b>Improve your front-end skills by building projects</b></p>
            <p class="subtext">Scan the QR code to visit Frontend Mentor and take your coding skills to the next level</p>
            <button>Sign up!</button>  
        </div>

        <div class="container-sub">
            <h3>£35 <span>p/m</span></h3>
            <p><b>Improve your front-end skills by building projects</b></p>
            <p class="subtext">Scan the QR code to visit Frontend Mentor and take your coding skills to the next level</p>
            <button>Sign up!</button>  
        </div>

        <div class="container-sub">
            <h3>£90 <span>p/m</span></h3>
            <p><b>Improve your front-end skills by building projects</b></p>
            <p class="subtext">Scan the QR code to visit Frontend Mentor and take your coding skills to the next level</p>
            <button>Sign up!</button>  
        </div>
    </section>
```

CSS

```
article {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60vh;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 2em 0;
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    font-size: 3em;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    transform: rotate(-5deg);
    
}

article h2 {
    flex-shrink:0; 
    flex-basis: 100%;
    transform: rotate(5deg);
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 1em;
}

article img {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    transform: rotate(5deg);
}

article p {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: end;
    align-items: center;
    max-width: 40%;
    font-size: .5em;
    text-align: center;
    letter-spacing: .1em;
    transform: rotate(5deg);
    padding-left: 4em;
    border-top: 2px solid black;
    border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}

#services {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60vh;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 2em 0;
    color: white;
    font-size: 3em;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

#services h2 {
    flex-shrink:0; 
    flex-basis: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

#services img {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 65%;
    width: auto;
}

#services p {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    max-width: 40%;
    font-size: .5em;
    text-align: center;
    letter-spacing: .1em;
    padding-right: 4em;
    padding-bottom: 4em;
    border-top: 2px solid white;
    border-bottom: 2px solid white;
}

#pricing {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60vh;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 2em 0;
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    font-size: 3em;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    transform: rotate(-355deg);
    
}

#pricing h2 {
    flex-shrink:0; 
    flex-basis: 100%;
    transform: rotate(355deg);
    text-align: center;
}

.container-sub {
    height: 7.5em;
    width: 5em;
    margin: auto;
    border-radius: .6rem;
    justify-items: center;
    background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px 5px hsl(220, 15%, 55%);
    transform: rotate(355deg);
}

.container-sub h3 {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Chakra Petch', sans-serif;
    padding: 1em;
    
}

.container-sub span {
    font-size: .25em;
}

.container-sub p {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;    
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    max-width: 250px;

}

.subtext {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;    
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    max-width: 250px;
    padding: 2em .5em 0 .5em;
    color: hsl(220, 15%, 55%);
}

.container-sub button {
    margin: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By adding `overflow-x: hidden;` on body you can fix the scrolling issue.
Regarding the alignment on pricing I don't think there's a way to do it with the markup and styling you have.

My suggestion is to place the rotation not in the section but on a different element which goes behind it via css. In my example I used the `before` pseudo-element.

Please check:

```css
body {
  margin: 4em 0;
  background-color: black;
}

.section {
  position: relative;
  padding: 4em;
}

.section::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0 30px;
  background-color: white;
  transform: rotate(-355deg);
}

.section > * {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.section > .title {
  text-align: center;
}

.plans {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 2em;
}

.plan {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 2em;
  width: 7em;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 1px solid hsl(220, 15%, 55%);
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px 5px hsl(220, 15%, 55%);
}
```

```html
<section class="section">
  <h2 class="title">Pricing</h2>

  <div class="plans">
    <article class="plan">
        <h3 class="price">£15<span>p/m</span></h3>
        <p class="short-description">Improve your front-end skills by building projects</p>
        <p class="description">
          Scan the QR code to visit Frontend Mentor and take your coding skills to the next level
        </p>
        <button class="button">Sign up!</button>  
    </article>

    <article class="plan">
        <h3 class="price">£25<span>p/m</span></h3>
        <p class="short-description">Improve your front-end skills by building projects</p>
        <p class="description">
          Scan the QR code to visit Frontend Mentor and take your coding skills to the next level
        </p>
        <button class="button">Sign up!</button>  
    </article>

    <article class="plan">
        <h3 class="price">£35<span>p/m</span></h3>
        <p class="short-description">Improve your front-end skills by building projects</p>
        <p class="description">
          Scan the QR code to visit Frontend Mentor and take your coding skills to the next level
        </p>
        <button class="button">Sign up!</button>  
    </article>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Awesome, the overflow-x comment worked with the scrolling, but how to I now make the rotated div appear across the whole screen? at the moment it looks like a rotated rectangle? Thanks

Comment: Sorry, not quite sure if I got your question. Isn't it supposed to be a rotated div? Can you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: Sorry, yep definitely supposed to be a rotated div, my issue is that now that i've rotated it, I can see the white edges of the on the left and right sides of my screen rather than just being completely angled white across the screen, does that make sense? 

Check my demo site here and you should see what I mean - https://jacwilalasey.github.io/Smart-Contrax/

Comment: Ah, I thought you wanted it like that. In that case you don't need the `overflow-x`, just have to play with the position (`inset`) of the `::before` pseudo-element to find a compromise with the rotation angle. Edited the snipped, please check.